# Cannot connect to Infura

Tags: infura

I recently registered to  Infura and trying to connect to the Ethereum Mainnet using the command below (`{MY_PROJECT_ID}` is swapped for my actual project id)

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
>       -X POST \
>       -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_getBalance","params":["0xfe05a3e72235c9f92fd9f2282f41a8154d6d342b", "latest"]]}' \
>       ropsten.infura.io/v3/{MY_PROJECT_ID}
```

It times out and outputs the following error here: https://gist.github.com/Genysys/6bbb8eb6415cd3c6c6b591dee741db91

I have tried other networks but run into the same issue.

I would be appreciative of any pointers on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the network i was connecting from. Had to Hotspot off my phone and it works now